# How to access Firestore from Angular HttpClinet

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection with following security rules

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

**if I fetch it from chrome address bar,**

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/q?key={apiKey}
```

it gives me a result

```
    {
      "documents": [
        {
        
  "name": "projects/{projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/q/w",
      "fields": {
        "e": {
          "stringValue": "r"
        },
        "d": {
          "stringValue": "f"
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2023-10-27T01:46:05.007011Z",
      "updateTime": "2023-10-27T01:54:56.018251Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

**if I fetch it from Angular HttpClient I have an error**

```
url = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/q?key={apiKey}'

request() {
  return this.httpClient.get(this.url)
}

this.service.request().subscribe((val) => console.log(val))
```

```
code: 403
message: "Missing or insufficient permissions."
status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

I want to make the same result, as from address bar

Comment: did you used the same apiKey in both cases?

Comment: yes, I use the same apiKey

Comment: ok, I think it related to auth issue,. first try fetch it from firefox or edge, the point is in chrome, you already loged in int your project, so if you want to try it in chrome, signout from your project from firebase then try it, I think you will get 403 error. so try this first just to confirm its an auth issue.